# ASP.NET form submit part of a model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, request

This is just something that has been puzzling me, I'm wondering if there's a built in way for this.

Say you have a `Package` class

```
public class Package 
{
    public A AObject { get; set; }
    public B BObject { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a view that uses this `Package`.

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    return View(new Package());
}
```

Now the view will accept this model and have 2 forms.

```
@model Path.To.Package

@Html.BeginForm("SubmitA", "MyController")
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AObject.SomeProperty);
    <input type="submit" />
}
@Html.BeginForm("SubmitB", "MyController")
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BObject.AnotherProperty);
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

If one would create two actions needed above that take `Package` as argument, this would work without question...

```
 public JsonResult SubmitA(Package items) { ... }
 public JsonResult SubmitB(Package items) { ... }
```

But at `SubmitA` the BObject would be null and in `SubmitB` AObject would be null.

My question here is whether you can submit only a part of the model? So the first form would only submit `AObject` and the second `BObject` so you could actually reach these via the following actions:

```
public JsonResult SubmitA (A a) { ... }
public JsonResult SubmitB (B b) { ... }
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 forms? You can only submit one form. But yes, you can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` - `public JsonResult SubmitA ([Bind(Prefix = "AObject ")]A a) { ... }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The real-life reason behind a scenario of 2 forms is a bit lengthy, but yes, I only need one form to be submitted (at a time), but only to pass the appropriate type/object to the Action that I'm calling with that form (I hope that makes sense). Otherwise I think you for the Prefix thing! You can post below in the answers, get yourself some points :)

Comment: @NemanjaT Even in your case, it is only ONE part of the model that is submitted. The submitted Form data only has values corresponding to the submitted form fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` to bind to complex properties of a model. The attribute effectively removes the prefix from the submitted name/value pairs when binding to model.

Your controller methods would be

```
public JsonResult SubmitA([Bind(Prefix = "AObject")]A model) { ... }
public JsonResult SubmitB([Bind(Prefix = "BObject")]B model) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use separate view model for each form. You can of course, use bind attribute or use specific property names in the controller action. But, that doesn't solve your real problem. You can only get either of the values and the other object will be unassigned or NULL. This is why you should have separate view model for each view / form. You can build your Package object once you have values for both objects.